# CloudFormation cannot find subnet it just made

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I am trying to make a subnet and then make an ENI in it; the subnet is reported created, and then creation of the ENI fails saying the subnet is not found:

16:49:06 UTC-0600   CREATE_COMPLETE AWS::EC2::Subnet    subnet0
.....
16:49:10 UTC-0600   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface  CSReniA The subnet ID 'subnet0' does not exist

I use these two resource stanzas:

```
"subnet0": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "10.100.0.0/24",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
    "VpcId": {
      "Ref": "vpcfde3149b"
    },
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Base"
      }
    ]
  }
},

"CSReniA" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
  "DependsOn": [
    "subnet0"
  ],
  "Properties" : {
    "Tags": [{"Key":"Name","Value":"CSReniA"}],
    "Description": "primary interface for CSR ingress and for transit local routes",
    "SourceDestCheck": "false",
    "GroupSet": ["sgalltraffic"],
    "SubnetId": "subnet0",
    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.100.0.30"
  }
},
```

Is there a better/different way?
Any suggestion greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Victor, if the answer has helped you solve the problem please mark it as correct to award the author for the time he spent helping you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! the answer is correct, but I am quite new on serverfault and I cannot find a button or anything to mark it as correct - how is it done?

Comment: there is a little grey "tick" icon under under the up/down voting arrows on the left hand side from my answer. When you hover over it it will say something about accepting the answer. Click it, it will turn green and it's done. You must be logged in to do it of course. Glad I could be of a help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
"SubnetId": "subnet0",
```

use a reference to the subnet resource:

```
"SubnetId": { "Ref": "subnet0" },
```

That will work :)